# Minimize Maximize is not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The minimize & maximize Button is not working 
The code is 
I want to minimize & maximize this div & also how to set the height of div box.It is just as extra as height of title bar because i give height as 100%

```js
$(function() {
  $("#main").resizable();
});
$("#button").click(function() {
  if ($(this).html() == "-") {
    $(this).html("+");
    $(this).slideUp();
  } else {
    $(this).html("-");
    $(this).slideDown();
  }
  $("#box").slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="main" id="main">
  <div id="title_bar">
    <div id="button">-</div>
  </div>
  <div id="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is a fiddle that might help you : https://jsfiddle.net/p45dvrap/1/
And can you give a clear description for your second point "& also how to set the height of div box"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code : I have commented two lines of your code `$(this).slideUp();`  and `$(this).slideDown();` this lines show/hide on click of that link.

```js
        $(function () {
            $("#main").resizable();
        });
        $("#button").click(function () {
            if ($(this).html() == "-") {
                $(this).html("+");
                //$(this).slideUp();
            } else {
                $(this).html("-");
                //$(this).slideDown();
            }
            $("#box").slideToggle();
        });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<body>
<div class="main" id="main"> 
        <div id="title_bar">
        <div id="button">-</div>
    </div>
    <div id="box" style="height:200px;border:1px red solid">
    This is box
    </div>
</div> 
</body>
```

Comment: Yaa no action is there on click

Comment: It is not working in code snippet but not in my codde

Comment: Yaa its done now one issue is there taht when i resize the boz then how to get the current width & height of the divs so that when the page load again it remains in same size.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some content inside the div box, so i added a fixed height ot demonstrate the function.

And you were sliding the button div which will hide it prevent you from click on it again.

See snippet bellow on how to do it:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#main").resizable();
});
$("#button").click(function() {
  if ($(this).html() == "-") {
    $(this).html("+");
    $("#main").css('height', 'auto');
    $("#main").resizable('disable');

  } else {
    $(this).html("-");
    $("#main").resizable('enable');

  }
  $("#box").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
#box {
  height: 100px;
}

#button {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

#main {
  border: 1px solid;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="main" id="main">
  <div id="title_bar">
    <div id="button">-</div>
  </div>
  <div id="box">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Tech what is not working ? can you provide some info!

Comment: It is also not working I just need to minimize & maximize the divs

Comment: @Tech in my answer minimize and maximize is working fine, so what problem do you exactly have?

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).slideDown();` in the buttons function will simply slide the button, remove them and you're basically good to go!

```js
$(function() {
  $("#main").resizable();
});
$("#button").click(function() {
  if ($(this).html() == "-") {
    $(this).html("+");
  } else {
    $(this).html("-");
  }
  $("#box").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
#button {
  background: lightblue;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

#box {
  background: coral;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="main" id="main">
  <div id="title_bar">
    <div id="button">+</div>
  </div>
  <div id="box">
    Hello World!
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
  $("#main").resizable();   
  
  $("#button").click(function() {
    if ($(this).html() == "-") {
      $(this).html("+");
      $(this).slideDown();
    } else {
      $(this).html("-");
      $(this).slideDown();
    }
    $("#box").slideToggle();
  });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="main" id="main">
    
    <div id="title_bar">
        <div id="button">-</div>
    </div>
    <div id="box">Hi
    </div>
</div>
```